# Как растянуть абсолютный элемент по высоте родителя?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы высота абсолютного элемента была равна высоте родителя, то есть резиновой. Как это сделать? Или может есть альтернативные решения?

Comment: Добавьте в тело вопроса проблемный кусок кода с Вашего сайта. Ссылки на сайты, которые нужно "починить" здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: Почему вам не подходит `height: 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/yas30p5k/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант вот так прописать:

```
height: 100%;
```

Comment: контент будет вылазить , и вроде абсолютные не тянутся , height 100% вариант  но не ответ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```